# Listening to context Refreshed in Spring cloud consul config

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-consul

Spring cloud consul config allows dynamic refresh of properties whenever the property is changed in consul. Is there a way to  listen whenever the change happens?

```
@Component
public class ContextRefreshListener {

@EventListener
public void handleContextRefresh(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("refreshed");
}

@EventListener
public void handleContextStart(ContextStartedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("started");
}


@EventListener
public void handleContextRefresh(ApplicationContextEvent event) {
    System.out.println("context");
}
```

}

I tried the above three events, but no luck. Is there any way to do listen to events whenever the refresh happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it by following way

```
@EventListener
public void handleContextStart(EnvironmentChangeEvent event) {
    System.out.println("changed");
    //Use this for getting the version from consul

}
```